# Pointers and arrays in C with index

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have this in my code

```
char *ch = &(string[i]);
printf(ch);
```

and you want to print a certain elements in array and it prints nothing however if i change it to

```
char *ch = &(string[20]);
printf(ch);
```

it prints the content from space 20 and up, why is that and how can i attempt to fix this?

thanks in adavnce

Comment: What do you mean by "fix it"?  What behaviour do you want?

Comment: i is an int determined from a while loop and fix i mean for it to print from position i(int) to the end of that array

Comment: Then what is the value of `i`?

Comment: i varys depending of input of user

Comment: Ok... What was the value of `i` when nothing was printed?

Comment: @user998316: the point trying to be made is that `i` is likely to be wrong (or at least not what you're expecting).  If you set `i = 20` both examples will behave the same.

Comment: And it should probably be `printf("%s", string);` or `puts(string);`. String might contain a `"%"` or three.

Comment: And unrelated to your question: the variable name `ch` is a bad choice for a `char*` since it's pretty much always used as a name for  a plain old `char` variable. (when I first read your question I was wondering why the compiler didn't complain about assigning a pointer to a `char`, even though the type was *right there*).

Comment: i feel so dumb, they werent i forgot the array starts counting from 0 so i have to increment 1 to i, thank you Michael Burr

Answer (score 0):

`printf` on a `char *` will print everything until it hits a `\0` character because in c, strings are char*s.

if you just want to print a single character do:

```
printf("%c",ch[0]);
```

Comment: Not what he's asking. He wants to know why it doesn't print the rest of the string like it should.